# How to calculate factorial in ruby

Tags: ruby, factorial

**QUESTION** :

```
Input:
  4 # number of input 
  1
  2
  4
  3
Output:
  1
  2
  24
  6
```

**CANNOT GET DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
My code:
num  = Integer(gets.chomp)
k = []
for i in 1..num
k[i] = Integer(gets.chomp)
end

k.each do |w|
for i in 1..w
w.to_i = w*i
end
puts w 
end
```

Comment: What is `w.to_i = w*i` supposed to mean? How can you assign to the result of a `to_i` call?

Comment: Instead of asking for "give me the code" if you could ask "help me to figure it out", at least you would not get so many downvotes!

Comment: you need to describe your problem better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like:

```
input = Integer(gets.chomp) 
ans = 1
for i in 1..input
 ans = ans*i
end
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get factorial of `n`

```
(1..n).inject :*
```

To take care of zero

```
(1..n).inject(1, :*)
```